Failed to fetch error when submitting the form to add data to backend
I'm having this error while i submit the form i made to add data to backend.

when i add the details in the form and click submit then instead of adding the data to backend, it shows this error. And when I run the backend on termina l(it's running on port-5000), initially when i see "http://localhost:5000" it runs fine without any error but when i reload the "http://localhost:5000", without doing any changes it gives this error on the terminal:
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
connected successfully
running successfully at 5000
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);      
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\projects\mern-app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:795:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v18.16.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This is the Create.jsx file in which the form is coded along with the handleSubmit function.
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Create=()=>{
    const [name,setName]=useState("");
    const [email,setEmail]=useState("");
    const [age,setAge]=useState(0);
    const [error,setError]=useState("");
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    console.log(name,email,age);

    const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        var addUser={name,email,age};
        const response=await fetch("http://localhost:5000",{
            method:"POST",
            body:JSON.stringify(addUser),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(addUser),
        });

    const result=await response.json();
    if(!response.ok){
        console.log(result.error);
        setError(result.error);
    }
    if(response.ok){
        console.log(result);
        setError("");
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setAge(0);
        setError("");
        navigate("/all");
    }
    };
    return (
       <div className='container my-2'>
       <h2 className='tect-center'>enter data</h2>
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <div className="mb-3">
    <label  className="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} />
  </div>
  <div className="mb-3">
    <label className="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control"value={email} onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)} />
  </div>
  <div className="mb-3">
    <label  className="form-label">age</label>
    <input type="number" className="form-control" value={age} onChange={(e)=>setAge(e.target.value)}/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
   
)}
export default Create;

